# Is Clare W. Graves a credible author?

Tags: social-psychology

I stumbled upon the book ["The never ending quest"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0972474218) by [Clare W. Graves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clare_W._Graves). It looks interesting to me, but I suspect that he is not as scientific as he pretends to be. Is this author's theory of hierarchy considered credible?

Comment: I met one of Clare Grave's secrataries back in the late 80's. Her take on the question was that Clare Graves had next to no research to show for his theories, but a lot of influence with the american security apparatus. And was providing a theoretical model to justify the invasion of "less developped countries" and the whole nation building meme by americans abroad.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  Clare W. Graves was a contemporary of Maslow.  He and Maslow used to go back and forth – as Graves thought Maslow's theory was incomplete (too closed).  At the end, Maslow agreed with Graves.  Graves died before much of his work was really accepted.  Cowan and Beck carried on his work.

It is, in my humble opinion, the most brilliant explanation for human development ever created.  It covers humanity as individuals and as collections (cultures), and Graves also created a system of change theory that matched.

You'll find the most ardent advocate is [Don Beck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don_Beck_(management_consultant)), who was largely responsible (using the theories developed by Graves) to assist Mandela in South Africa.  It's called [Spiral Dynamics Integral](http://www.spiraldynamics.net/) now by Don Beck.  There are many who continue studying this work.

Research confirms it.  There is ongoing research ([Online PeopleScan](http://www.peoplescanservices.com/)) that is used by cutting-edge consultants in business and organizations.

Comment: This is the start of a really good answer. Would you mind providing links to the research that you're referencing?

Comment: I'd just like to note that the tagline on the linked [Spiral Dynamics Integral page](http://www.spiraldynamics.net) is "Spiral Dynamics Integral - The theory that explains everything", and they primarily seem to sell access to training and seminars. One man's "credible scientist" is another man's "quack".